# How to translate YUI Calendar widget?

Tags: calendar, locale, yui

I am using YUI calendar widget (http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/calendar/calendar-simple.html) and cannot find any way how to change month and day names to another language.

Can anybody help, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calendar actually supports a bunch of languages already.  Translations are handled by the intl module:  http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/intl/

Answer (score 1):

YUI's Calendar module currently supports many languages for Internationalization. You can use the feature by specifying `lang` option to YUI config object. Here is an example.

```
YUI({lang: "ja"}).use("calendar", function (Y) {

  var calendar = new Y.Calendar({
    contentBox: "#calendar"
  });

  calendar.render();

});
```